# Performing a Yup test validation based on a condition

Tags: validation, formik, yup

I have the following Yup validation schema, which is all working fine.

Within the validation schema there is a object name called `windowSelection` that can have the value of either `A` or `R`.

Based on this and the below schema, I only want to perform the `endDate` rule below when `windowSelection` is `A`

I was looking at:

```
endDate: Yup.date()
  .when("windowSelection", {
        is: 'A',
        then: Yup.date()
                 .nullable()
                 .required('End date is required')
                 .min(
                     Yup.ref('startDate'),
                     "End date must be greater than Start date"
                  )
                  .test({
                     // as below ....
      }),
```

but it didn't work.

```
  Yup.object().shape({
    myGroup: Yup.array()
            .of(
              Yup.object().shape({
                windowSelection: Yup.string()
                        .required('Selection is required'),
                dateInfo: Yup.object().shape({
                  startDate: Yup.date()
                    .nullable()
                    .required('Start date is required'),
                  startTime: Yup.date()
                    .nullable()
                    .required('Start time is required'),
                  endDate: Yup.date()
                    .nullable()
                    .required('End date is required')
                    .min(
                      Yup.ref('startDate'),
                      "End date must be greater than Start date"
                    )
                    .test({
                        name: "same",
                        exclusive: false,
                        params: {},
                        message: "End date must be greater than Start date",
                        test: function(value) {                        
                          const startDate = moment(this.parent.startDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + ' ' +
                                            moment(this.parent.startTime).format("HH:mm:ss")
                          const endDate = moment(value).format("DD/MM/YYYY") + ' ' +
                                          moment(this.parent.endTime).format("HH:mm:ss")
                          return !moment(startDate).isSame(moment(endDate))
                        },
                    }),
                  endTime: Yup.date()
                    .nullable()
                    .required('End time is required'),                    
                })
              }),
            ) 
  })
```

Any help would be great.